# Java program hangs in CMD but works just fine in JDeveloper. Why?

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and this would be my first post on this site.I have used it many times before, but this time I haven't found an answer to my problem so here I am..
  This code works great in my IDE (JDeveloper) but for some reason, when I run it in CMD it hangs for certain parameters (ex. 7844578642 2;7844578642 16 - the two sets work in IDE but not CMD).
  Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
class PR13_19 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long N = 0;
    int base = 0,pow = 1;
    String result = "";
    if(args.length != 2){
        System.out.println("Please enter Number and base...");
        return;
    }
    try{
        N = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        base = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        if(!(base >= 2 && base <= 16)) throw new NumberFormatException();
    }catch(NumberFormatException | StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exc){
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        return;
    }
      //converts number N in base 10 to any base "base"
      // if base >10 11=A,12=B,13=C....(ex.hexadecimal) 
   while(pow <= N/base)
      pow *= base; //greatest power of "base" >= N
   while(pow > 0){
       if(N >= pow) { 
           if(N/pow > 9) result += (char)((N/pow) + 55);
           else                  result += (N/pow);
           N -= (N - (N % pow));
       }
       else result += "0";
       pow /=base;
   }
   System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must enter a number defined in javas LONG scope or change the code.

You can also add try/catch clause to see which error occurs.